# How to access authenticated user in graphene-django resolve method?

Tags: django, graphene-django

I have added this to my `Query` class and it's returning null in response.

```
me = graphene.Field(UserType)

def resolve_user(root, info):
    logger.info("***** Inside resolve ****")
    return info.context.user
```

and my `UserType` is defined like this.

```
class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    fields = ["id", "name", "email", "username"]

    class Meta:
        model = User
```

I'm on Django==3.0 if it helps

I'm authenticated and the cookies are present. It's not even printing the log which is confusing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graphene fields use `resolve_<field>` pattern to resolve the values. Check more [here](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/objecttypes/#resolvers)

```
me = graphene.Field(UserType)
^^

def resolve_me(root, info):
    logger.info("***** Inside resolve ****")
    return info.context.user
```